# how minified error 130 can be solved in react-native?

Tags: react-native

https://snack.expo.dev/@ritesh_gupta2506/vd-holder-project

This is my react project
I am trying to learn drawer navigation but failed to run the program due to '' minified react error 130 ''
can you please find out the error and solve it

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. If you are stuck on a particular problem, you can ask questions. You can’t just ask people to debug code for you.